# How to take input from user in html and use that variable as .bg background url in css file

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, input

I have been working on this code where I need to take input from the user via HTML buttons and then assign that input URL of an image from the web to the .bg {background: URL('URL') } in my CSS file.
Is there some way I can do that?

```
.bg {
    background: URL(' *user input image URL * ')
}
```

This is the project I have been originally working on, so I wanted the URL input from the user and then display the blurry loading post that using the input from the user
https://github.com/bradtraversy/50projects50days/tree/master/blurry-loading

Answer (score 0):

So as you see here I am updating the background after 3 seconds. This will not change the css file but will change the css in real time. All you need to do is update what is stored in the background style portion of the element. You just need the link to the image. If you want to update permanently in the css there are 2 ways to go about it, keeping the css the same and changing the reference file or writing to the css file with a different script and reloading.

```js
setTimeout(function () {
   document.getElementById("bg").style.background ="URL('https://i.picsum.photos/id/866/200/300.jpg?hmac=rcadCENKh4rD6MAp6V_ma-AyWv641M4iiOpe1RyFHeI')";
}, 3000);
```

```css
   #bg {
    color: blue;
    background: URL('https://i.picsum.photos/id/237/200/300.jpg?hmac=TmmQSbShHz9CdQm0NkEjx1Dyh_Y984R9LpNrpvH2D_U');
    height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="bg"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do like this

```js
function setImage() {
  const input_from_user = document.getElementById("input_from_user");
  const image_url = input_from_user.value;
  
  const bg_container = document.getElementsByClassName("bg")[0];
  bg_container.style.backgroundImage = `url(${image_url})`;
}
```

```css
.bg {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="bg"></div>
    <input type="url" id="input_from_user" />
    <button onclick="setImage()">Set Image</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Can try with this image: https://www.google.nl/images/srpr/logo3w.png

Hope this can help.

Comment: This is the project i have been originally working on, so I wanted to the URL input from the user and then display the blurry loading post that
https://github.com/bradtraversy/50projects50days/tree/master/blurry-loading